# Laravel progress bar gets overwritten

Tags: php, laravel

I have a command where I do 3 loops, I want to show 3 progress bars for every loop.
In my output the progress bar gets overwritten and I can only see 1.

My code:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->setUsers('a', UserModel::all()->where('type', 'a'));
    $this->setUsers('b', UserModel::all()->where('type', 'b'));
    $this->setUsers('c', UserModel::all()->where('type', 'c'));
}


private function setUsers(string $type, $users)
{
    $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($users));
    $bar->start();

    /** @var UserModel $user */
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->update(['type' => [$type]]);
        $bar->advance();
    }

    $bar->finish();
}
```

[image]

The goals here is to see 3 progress bars that have completed.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I add a new line into the output:

```
private function setUsers(string $type, $users)
{
    $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($users));
    $bar->start();

    /** @var UserModel $user */
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->update(['type' => [$type]]);
        $bar->advance();
    }

    print "\n";

    $bar->finish();
}
```

You can also find good examples [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10356), like displaying all progress bars at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate section like [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html#displaying-multiple-progress-bars)

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;

...

private $symOutput;
public function run(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->symOutput = $output;
    return parent::run($input, $output);
}

public function handle()
{
    $this->setUsers('a', UserModel::all()->where('type', 'a'));
    $this->setUsers('b', UserModel::all()->where('type', 'b'));
    $this->setUsers('c', UserModel::all()->where('type', 'c'));
}


private function setUsers(string $type, $users)
{
    $section = $this->symOutput->section();
    $bar = new ProgressBar($section, count($users));
    $bar->start();

    /** @var UserModel $user */
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->update(['type' => [$type]]);
        $bar->advance();
    }

    $bar->finish();
}
```